# Linq to Entity Framework 4 query counting but not returning results

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, c#-4.0

I have a query like:

```
var fooQuery = (from x in edm.stuff where x.col == DesiredVal select x)
```

'stuff' is a view.  When I count the results I get '1'.  When I First() or FirstOrDefault() I get null.

```
var fooCount = fooQuery.Count(); // results in 1
var fooResult = fooQuery.FirstOrDefault(); // results in null
```

This doesn't make sense to me.  Is there a circumstance that this *should* be happening?

Comment: Well, I don't think it's possible. Try to examine resulting SQL. I do think the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, it sounds weird indeed. Have you tried Any(), Single(), ToList()? What do those return?

Comment: Since it was a view, I had arbitrary indexes and I had built a relationship and a navigation property on the column (which was nvarchar).  The column in the view came from a outer join, and so was sometimes null and when it wasn't it was not always present in the adjoining (created through the entity designer) normal table.  I could count it was there, but could not retrieve it with First() or Any().  I did not try the others.  This is obviously a fringe case.  Could this be a bug?  Maybe I should build an example.

Answer (score 0):

are you using a private member in the where statement?

Comment: not sure what would create a private member.  the 'id' column is a database column.

Comment: I did see how to make members private.  No that is not my problem.  Interesting thought though.

Comment: what i mean is that in the class you ahve public properties which write to and from the private members. When you write you linq you can use either of these, but only the public property ones will work as intended.